# Set values based on variable keys in a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using an automation library in Python which has this syntax:

```
Name.parameters(Var1 = 'variable name 1')
```

So by running this I can assign "variable name 1" to "Var1". This works without any problem.
The issue is that I have like 40 variables that I need to assign names to. To avoid writing them by hand, I was thinking to use a for loop instead.

So I'm trying to have something like this:

```
for i in range(40):
    var_i = str("Var"+i)
    var_name_i = str("variable name "+i)
    Name.parameters(var_i = var_name_i)
```

The problem is that this does not work. So I'm trying to find a way to access/change values of a dictionary while dict keys are defined by a variable.

Comment: try replacing in "str("Var"+i)" and str("variable name "+i) with "str(i)"

Answer (score 3):

Use keyword argument expansion(**) with a dictionary:

```
for i in range(40):
    Name.parameters(**{f'Var{i}': f'variable name {i}'})
```

If you function can take multiple parameters, this could work by using a dictionary comprehension to generate all parameters at once:

```
params = {f'Var{i}': f'variable name {i}' for i in range(40)}
Name.parameters(**params)
```

Comment: This worked beautifully!